# Reference request: functional equation of real analytic Eisenstein series of weight $k$

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

I want to do some computations which require the functional equations of the following real analytic Eisenstein series of weight $k$:
$$E_k(z, s)=\sum_{(c, d) \in \mathbf{Z}^2 \backslash(0,0)} \frac{y^s}{(c z+d)^k|c z+d|^{2 s}},$$
but I couldn't find any related reference.

In standard references, for example:

- Bump, Automorphic Forms and Representations, it only deals with $k=0$ example;
- Miyake, Modular Forms, in the last chapter, last section, it computes in great detail the Fourier expansion of this Eisenstein series (following Shimura), but without discussion on the functional equation.

Could anybody tell me some other related literature? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This is all kind of well-known but it is sometimes difficult to find explicit references. We collect some formulae of this type in section 4.2 of my paper with Lei and Zerbes "Euler systems for Rankin--Selberg convolutions of modular forms" (Ann of Math, 2014). (When $\alpha = 0$, our Eisenstein series $E_\alpha$ and $F_\alpha$ coincide, and both are equal to your $E_k(z, s)$ up to a normalisation factor.)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Ah thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

(Posting this as an answer because I just bountied a post and don't have enough to comment)
Try checking out these to begin with:

1. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.10696.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.06284.pdf
2. [https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_c/simplest_eis.pdf](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/mfms/notes_c/simplest_eis.pdf)
3. https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/scanned/IntroductionToModularForms/fulltext.pdf

Was that what you were looking for?

How about?

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40687-018-0151-3

In the above one they deal with a generalization of the following Eisentsein series you have
$$E_{k-1, 2s-1}(z)=\sum_{(c, d) \in \mathbf{Z}^2 \backslash(0,0)} \frac{\ln\mid q\mid}{(c z+d)^{k}(c \bar{z}+d)^{2s}},$$

multiplied by some constant term dependant on $s$ and $k$, with $q=e^{2\pi i \tau}$

Comment: It seems that still I couldn’t find what I need. Garrett and Zagier’s notes, and Goldfeld’s preprint only deal with weight 0 case. Another preprint deals with Siegel Eisenstein series, but the formula in the definition is not the same as the formula in my question.

Comment: Does the last one help?

Comment: These are different objects, I think. This is not the Eisenstein series in my question.

Comment: Let me know if you want me to close this then- That was the closest I could find, other than the weight 0 case. Best of luck! If I manage to come across it I will link it as a comment (now that I have enough reputation again)